# TextWriterTraceListener : can I reset/clear the output log via app.config?

Tags: c#, .net, tracelistener, trace-listener

I have looked at the properties of the `TextWriterTraceListener` class and it parents and dont' see a way to add a propery to the app.config so that the log file is reset/cleared when the `TraceWriter` opens the file.

Comment: You need to give more context, in particular: what language/framework are you using? Please add the relevant tag by editing your question.

Comment: I have C# application using .NET 4.5 that uses a TextWriterTraceListener to generate a log of activity. I was looking for a way to control whether or not this log is cleared using some setting in the application config file. I would rather not have this intelligence embedded in the application so that I can control the number of trace listeners and their behavior from the config file

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the logs on appdomain start up is a surprising behavior-- most libraries are reluctant to destroy data. Creating a new file on start up or every-so-often is a more common scenario.

If the built in listeners don't meet your needs, try Essential Diagnostics (Extends Systems.Diagnostics tracing)

Ref: https://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RollingFileTraceListener&referringTitle=FileLogTraceListener

Also: https://ukadcdiagnostics.codeplex.com/

And, again, assuming you are using Systems.Diagnostics for legit reasons, then you might consider extending TextWriterTraceListener & overriding the behavior you don't like and replacing it (say by adding file deletion to the constructor).

(And someone will recommend switching to log4net or nlog which have more feature to start with, so there is that)